# How to change the popupbackground of odd numbers of a spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I query the database and returns me numbers and put them in the spinner.

Then the property to change the background color of the spinner drop is setpopupbackround.

But what I want to do is, go odd red and green pairs.

As is done ?, it is not setpopupbackround?

I want to get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRuy0.png)

Comment: just change adapter layout background on base of adapter position